# Socket connection ends with Operation now in progress on non-blocking socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a problem with connecting to a destination IP using **connect()** API. The **connect()** API returns a `-1` and errno as `operation in progress`

. Am I checking the return code too early before it establishes a connection? Please see the following code snippet:

```
struct sockaddr_in      servAddr;
        servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            servAddr.sin_port = htons(9190); 
        const char * remoteIp = 10.10.20.86;
            rc = inet_pton(AF_INET,remoteIp, &servAddr.sin_addr);
            if (rc == -1 || errno == EAFNOSUPPORT)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            rc = connect(fd, (sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
         if ( rc < 0) // this is where it fails. rc is -1.
                   {
                        log("connect failure with [%s]",strerror(errno));
                        print_sock_connect_error();
                   }
```

I have 2 questions here:

1. The destination IP and port `10.10.20.86:9190` is waiting for a connection and once the connection is received, it  send the ack back to the source. I see the tcp established  - ACK,SYN/ACK and ACK to destination - in *pcap* but still couldn't figure out why it returns `-1` with error. So Am I checking the rc before the connection establishment is complete? `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries` is set to 6.
2. Is there anything wrong with the code above?

Comment: Please don't spam with tags. Even if the problem might be applicable to both C and C++, only use the tags of the language you're actually program in, since that will influence the possible solutions there are.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your condition to check for errors from [`inet_pton`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) is flawed. You return `0` if there is an error, or if there's *no* error but `errno` just happens to be `EAFNOSUPPORT`. If there's no error (that is, when `inet_pton` don't return `-1`) then the value of `errno` is indeterminate and unknown. Don't check it then.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I checking the rc before the connection establishment is complete?

Yes, you are. The TCP ping-pong during the connection's set up isn't all that has to be done.

> Is there anything wrong with the code above?

Well, yes, either the way it handles the `EINPROGRESS` case or that is uses a non-blocking socket to connect.

From `connect()`'s Linux [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html):

> **EINPROGRESS**
>
> The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be
>                 completed immediately.  It is possible to select(2) or poll(2)
>                 for completion by selecting the socket for writing.  After
>                 select(2) indicates writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the
>                 SO_ERROR option at level SOL_SOCKET to determine whether
>                 connect() completed successfully (SO_ERROR is zero) or
>                 unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error codes
>                 listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. 10.10.20.86:9190 is waiting for a connection and once the connection is received, it send the ack back to the source. I see the tcp established - ACK,SYN/ACK and ACK to destination - in pcap but still couldn't figure out why it returns -1 with error. So Am I checking the rc before the connection establishment is complete?

Of course you are. You're checking it immediately `connect()` returns. As you have put the socket into non-blocking mode, there is no chance the three-way wire handshake will have completed by then.

> sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries is set to 6.

Irrelevant.

> 2. Is there anything wrong with the code above?

Only that it doesn't make sense.

- If you want he connection complete or failed before `connect()` returns, don't use non-blocking mode.
- If you want to use non-blocking mode, you have to use `select()` to tell you when the connect attempt has completed. Select for the socket becoming writeable. (That doesn't necessarily mean it *has* become writeable: it means the connect attempt has completed, with a result you can discover via `getsockopt()/SO_ERROR`.)